# Javascript logic handling: true & true = false?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that checks quantity settings when a customer clicks Add to Cart.

On this site, it is possible to toggle on/off whether fractional quantities are allowed.

e.g.: a shirt can only be sold in whole units, but a protein powder can be sold in partial per kg quantities.  (0.5, 1, 1.5, etc)

In my Javascript, I'm checking if the fractional quantities is allowed, and whether the customer has entered a fractional quantity.

```
if ((allowFractionalQty === 0) && (quantity % 1 !== 0)) {
    errorMsg = "Only whole numbers may be entered";
    validator.showErrors(errorMsg);
}
```

For some reason, when quantity = 1.5, and allowFractionalQty = 0, the result of the if statement is False.

I don't understand why, since

```
allowFractionalQty === 0  --> true
quantity % 1 !== 0  --> true
```

but

```
((allowFractionalQty === 0) && (quantity % 1 !== 0)) --> false
```

So why does it render as False?

Comment: probably because one of the expressions is actually evaluating to false. I recommend going in with a debugger and confirming that all values in there are actually what you expect them to be

Comment: As others have said, from the information you've given us, it will evaluate to true. There's something else going on if it's evaluating to false for you. Can you include some runnable code that actually shows it evaluating to false?

Comment: If `allowFractionalQty === 0` is *really* `true`, and if `quantity % 1 !== 0` is *really* true, then what you say is happening is not possible. Are you *sure* you're not checking string values with `!=` instead of `!==`?

Comment: Why is `allowFractionalQty` not a boolean True or False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything should work in your code, but I think, you should add some additionals for right types:: parseInt() and Number()

```js
((parseInt(allowFractionalQty) === 0) && (Number(quantity) % 1 !== 0))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a code block rather than a snippet if your intent is not for the code to be run?

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use `parseInt()` or `Number()` on values that are already numeric. If `allowFractionalQty === 0` is `true`, then that means the value in `allowFractionalQty` is already a number.

Comment: I'm picking this as the right answer. :-)  Reason is that I did indeed need a `parseInt` on the `allowFractionalQty` variable.  That value was been passed from PHP, and Javascript was seeing it as a string.

Comment: @Tim that means that your assertion that `allowFractionalQty === 0` was `true` was not correct in the first place.

Comment: @Pointy - don't be picky.

Answer (score 1):

While testing your input, it looks like the JavaScript works fine:

```js
var allowFractionalQty = 0;
var quantity = '1.5';

console.log(allowFractionalQty === 0);
console.log(quantity % 1 !== 0 )
console.log((allowFractionalQty === 0) && (quantity % 1 !== 0))
```

You may run into some type conflict if you compare string with number as below:

```
var allowFractionalQty = '0';
if (allowFractionalQty === 0) --> false
```

Comment: Well it proves the logic wasn't wrong.  As per your update, turns out Javascript was seeing the value (passed from PHP) as a string.  But I have to give the tick to Slawa, since he figured that first.

Comment: It looks like his solution blindly turns everything into numbers. This expression `quantity % 1` will always produce a number so no need to add explicit conversion. Only the first expression could clash different types which was stated above.